# How to reference image in data attribute within Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new on Rails. I can use images with `image_tag` or `image_path`.

But , i have an html template and these methods does not work in data-attributes. In my html , there is a `data-background` attribute which changes background of the `div`.

My html  :

```
<section id="sub-header" class="section bg-parallax pt-0 pb-0" data-background="<%= image_path('bg/about.jpg') %>">
```

This directory is under the `app/assets/images/bg`. But i can't reach the image.

Where should i put these images ? and how can i reach images in this example

Comment: You should put your images in the asset pipeline: `app/assets/images/bg/about.jpg`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Perhaps eliminate a variable by making sure it works with `image_tag` first.

Comment: it works with image_tag. But it does not work with data attribute

Comment: Okay, so Rails is not your problem then.  Is there some javascript/css plugin you are using that allows you to set image backgrounds via data attributes?  Background images are typically done using CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried all combinations. But solution was simple. You don't need to use rails helper functions for that. I moved my images from `assets` to `public` folder and :

```
  <section id="sub-header" class="section bg-parallax pt-0 pb-0" style='background:url("/bg/about.jpg")'>
```

Comment: `<%= content_tag(:section, class: "section bg-parallax pt-0 pb-0", id:"sub-header", data: { background: url("/bg/about.jpg")}) %>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this workaround :

```
data-background=<%=Rails.root.to_s + "path_to_your_image" %>
```

I know it' ugly  :/

Comment: Wouldn't it work to use image path instead of constructing one with rails root?

Comment: constructing one with rails root make that path universal .

Comment: if dont work localy it's because you have something wrong elsewhere.